# Django Rest Framework create user and user profile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create the view that will create new user using my API.
I am using a custom model for my User and also created a model called Profile to manage data that are not authentication related.

I am new to the Django world and it can be quite difficult.

Here is my models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('admin', default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    ordering = ('created',)

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Homme'),
        ('F', 'Femme'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)], blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: {0}'.format(self.user.email)


def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


def delete_user(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        instance.user.delete()
post_delete.connect(delete_user, sender=Profile)
```

Here is my serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'zip_code',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'profile', 'created',)
```

And here is the views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrWriteOnly,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return User.objects.all()
        else:
            return self.request.user

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        print serializer.__dict__
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print "valid"
        return Response("placeholder", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My goal is to be able to create the User and the Profile at the same time while being able to valid everything, how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Indeed, Django Rest Framework can't handle this job with nested relationships then you have to implement these methods yourself. I will give you some example of what your code should look like.

Your view :

```python
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrWriteOnly,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now, the `save` method of your serializer will call a `create` method when you want to create an object and `update` method when you want to update an object. So let's implement the `create` method of your `UserSerializer` which will create the profile and the user. Here is a simple example of what your `UserSerializer` should look like :

```python
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'profile', 'created',)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # create user 
        user = User.objects.create(
            url = validated_data['url'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            # etc ...
        )

        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        # create profile
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user = user
            first_name = profile_data['first_name'],
            last_name = profile_data['last_name'],
            # etc...
        )

        return user
```

As I said, this is an example, you have to complete it to do what you want to do but now, you know how to do it :) To define the behavior during an update, implement an `update` method.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a bit, even if I had started to figure this out, the create method is pretty easy to implement, but I must say that the update one is not.
Because for example in my UserSerializer I have a CharField for password and password confirmation, they are both required but whenever I want to update the use I need to provide both the passwords again.

Comment: Please update your question then, cause you talk about creation. Could you be more explicit about what you want to do in the update method, please?

Comment: Awesome man I was searching something like this, it is working like a charm, thank you @LouisBarranqueiro

Answer (score 3):

This might be late but why not bypass drf entirely and relegate profile creation trigger to models using signals like so:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
      pass
class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user =  models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer_profile')
      country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            user = instance
        )
```

this basically triggers a corresponding profile row creation once a user has been created via any means; admin, drf etc.

then you can use serializers to update the data.
hope this helps anyone else stumbling here

Comment: This approach is smart too. Nice approach

Comment: I wish to use this approach but need more guideline step by step

Comment: ohk, i was able to fix it, 
this is a repo  
https://github.com/olaneat/sch-market
where I used it
check the school-profile & register apps